# json- array structure valid or not

Tags: json

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this JSON structure?

```
   [
    "myDay": "Sun",
    "mytDate": "16/07/2017",
    "myRows": [{
        "myId": 1,
        "myTime": "11:00",
        "myNotesCount": 1,
    }],
    myHours": 110
    ]
```

Comment: wrap it in curly braces, myHours is missing quotation mark and the comma after last array element is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
    "myDay": "Sun",
    "mytDate": "16/07/2017",
    "myRows": [{
        "myId": 1,
        "myTime": "11:00",
        "myNotesCount": 1
    }],
    "myHours": 110
}
```

It should be:

- wrapped in `{}`
- no need comma after last element in array
- near `myHours` missed `"`